# Problem with embed in discord, doesn't write

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I write !time but the command is simply deleted and embed does not appear [image](https://sun9-69.userapi.com/Sju8dqA8-U_ucM1ht-O4bL02z4u_Au3-fbiOmw/j_U66HQvUwU.jpg)

```
@client.command(aliases = ['время'])
async def time(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed( colour = discord.Color.blue() )

    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    emb.set_author( name = ctx.author.name, icon_url= ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_footer( text = 'Приятного времяпрепровождения', icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    
    emb.set_thumbnail( icon_url = 'https://sun1.sibirix.userapi.com/ZrrVDtUgPy8BqsrY4iPa-8qQCLm_KHLaoyfWgQ/q5txWSzV1Zc.jpg' )

    now_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    emb.add_field( name ='501st LEGION', value = 'Дата и время: {}'.format( now_date ) )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

I can throw off the full code

Comment: Can you change your purge line to `await ctx.message.delete()` and see if that helps?

Comment: I replaced `await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )` on `await ctx.message.delete ()`didn help @EthanM-H

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Сmd is clean. the bot works @EthanM-H

Comment: Erm, it looks valid to me however I cant test it right now sorry.

Comment: Is it possible if the code is large that embed doesn't work ? ? line 357 @EthanM-H

Comment: I will run it myself later on and get back to you with an answer, hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was with the thumbnail.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['время'])
async def time(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.blue())

    await ctx.message.delete()

    emb.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text='Приятного времяпрепровождения',
                   icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)

    emb.set_thumbnail(url='https://sun1.sibirix.userapi.com/ZrrVDtUgPy8BqsrY4iPa-8qQCLm_KHLaoyfWgQ/q5txWSzV1Zc.jpg')

    now_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    emb.add_field(name='501st LEGION',value='Дата и время: {}'.format(now_date))

    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

You can also format the date output.using `now_date.strftime('%a, %b %e %H:%M:%S')` to be like this `Mon, Aug 17 11:24:56`

[image]

Comment: thanks @Abdulaziz . Where can I put it `now_date.strftime(%a, %b %e %H:%M:%S)`?

Comment: just below `now_date = datetime.datetime.now()` you add this `now_date = now_date.strftime('%a, %b %e %H:%M:%S')`